# Fortify Finding: OGNL Expression Injection: Double Evaluation

Tags: struts2, fortify

Need some help resolving a Fortify finding of OGNL Expression Injection: Double Evaluation

Here is the code that was flagged:

```
<tr>
    <td align=right><strong>Label Number:</strong></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="invForm.labelNumber" id="labelNumber" size="7" maxlength="7"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. The problem can't define.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that is what we were thinking after reviewing it but wanted a second opinion before suppressing it.

Comment: OGNL always used in JSP on the view layer to bind form fields with model objects. The conversion is performed indirectly when you submit a form. To read more about OGNL see